# Why is my wine cloudy now?

Tags: wine, sanitation, cloudy, safety, fining

[image]

This bottle of Mint wine was super clear when bottled. I use Sparkolloid. Six months later it looks like a snow globe. This is happening to several of my batches but not all.

Whats going on here ?

After some more thought, it seems the batches of wine without sediment where naturally more acidic. I don't know if that helps, but it is a common factor.

Comment: How many days between the use of Sparkolloid and bottling?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that some fermentation is still going on, and the sediment is yeast that, over time, has grown and multiplicated. If that's the case, you should open your bottles before they become timed bombs, which will explode in your cellar. Check if your wine is sparkling (even just a little bit), that gives an indication that fermentation is still occuring in the bottle.

If you did use some sort of sterilization, maybe you didn't use enough on those particular bottles. I use potassium metabisulfites, 2tsp per 20gal, and it's never managed to kill off all the yeast, which I don't mind in honey wine because it makes it sparkling, which I like.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you filter you will always have some level of yeast in suspension even when using a clarifier. Yet, that does seem like an unusual amount of sediment. Maybe try [isinglass](http://www.easternshoresbrewing.com/isinglass/?page_context=category&faceted_search=0) or [chitosan](http://www.easternshoresbrewing.com/chitosan/?page_context=category&faceted_search=0) in your next couple of batches to see of it makes a difference. From the picture it almost appears as it could be a pectic haze as well. Did you use [pectic enzyme](http://www.easternshoresbrewing.com/pectic-enzyme-1-oz/?page_context=category&faceted_search=0) in the fermenter?

Comment: I did add pectic at primary fermentation. Is that something that could happen over time?

Answer (score 0):

I have never encountered this before but is this any help to you: http://winemakersacademy.com/bottled-wine-cloudy/